# piecewise defined function finding at which points it is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

We have:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3 - 3x + 2 &\text{if }x \in \mathbb{Q}
\\ x^3 + x^2 + 4 &  \text{if }x \in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q \\ \end{cases} $$

I am trying to find the points at which f is continuous. I know about sequences but have just started continuous functions.

I used to following definition

$f$ is continuous at $ a $ if and only if for every sequence $x_n$ in the domain of $f$ such that $x_n\to a$, $ f(x_n)\to f(a) $.

Using this I found that the function is continuous at the points -2 and -1.

1) I can't be sure that my solution is complete/correct. Do I also need to prove discontinuity for all the other points? I showed that $ f(x_n)\to f(a) $ can only be true if $a = -2 $ or $a = -1$ is true.

2) Second question is, is there any other way to find the points at which a piecewise defined function like this is continuous? Can it be done using the continuity definition?

Comment: The function can only be continuous when the two polynomials coincide (that is at $-2$ and $-1$) because for every other point you can find suitable sequences of only rationals or only irrationals converging to the given points that will make continuity fail.

Comment: thanks for the answer yeah that makes sense